# Is there any way to add an attribute to a minified JS script tags in Nuxt?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, compilation, nuxt.js

We have an app, that minifies all necessary JS files. The way nuxt minfies the JS scripts when the app renders inside `<head>` is something along these lines:

```
<script src="/_nuxt/cc2978d89512be6a8374.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

My q is quite simple, how can we add an attribute to this file? Essentially turn that line into:

```
<script someAttribute src="/_nuxt/cc2978d89512be6a8374.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I've snooped around `nuxt.config.js` but can't seem to add it.
I also checked the Nuxt docs and cannot find anything relvant, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -2):

Maybe this?

```js
  var scripts = document.querySelectorAll('scripts');
  var l = 0;
  while (l<scripts.length) {
    if (scripts[l].src = '/_nuxt/cc2978d89512be6a8374.js') {
      scripts[l].setAttribute('NAME', 'VALUE');
    }
    l++;
  }
```

Comment: Those js files are bundles from nuxt building the app. I could run a function to target all `<script>` tags, but I only want the compressed/minfied js. that nuxt outputs rather then all script elements